# HOW to assign width automatically as per divice in ANDROID

Tags: android, xml

i am including 2 button in one page in single line and i don't want them to overlap so like html and css we can use (50%) as width to assign width automatically! is there any way we can do the same over here

i want a code which is assign width automatically as per divice width

`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout4">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/price"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_money">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/quantity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_storage_24">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constraints to ensure the buttons stay on the same line and are always besides one another, wrap content width should make sure they only take the space that they need, here is an example

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="button1"/>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="button2"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's how it would look
[Design screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UH13.png)